# Font size and font type changes after windows 10 update (appear too large and can't set it back)

Tags: windows-10, display, windows-update

I ran a Windows Update and afterwards all fonts in the windows menus, objects on desktop and windows explorer appear far too large, see screenshot. I tried to change this back using Settings --> Display --> Change the size of text. But the option is already at 100% (the minimum). Does anybody know what is going on with my system and how to change this back?

I also found advice [here](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-file-explorer-font-size-in-windows-10/) saying that there should be a 'rider' in the display settings to change text size. But this rider is not there in my version of Windows 10. In fact the display settings window looks as in the screenshot below.

Edit: This is the update that was installed: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-8-2022-kb5010342-os-builds-19042-1526-19043-1526-and-19044-1526-bd5c4434-bec4-42e9-991d-5810d4ec52d9

Examples of too large font in explorer:

[image]

Too large font on desktop:

[image]

Example from Chrome browser illustrates an ill difference of the font in the URL and menu/links (too large in menu/links)

[image]

My display settings:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a non default font that comes with a theme?

Comment: @MiG But I did not add this, I wouldn't even know how. Only thing I know is that it happened after an update.

Comment: Have a look at this.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-update-1903-may-2019-font-size-changes/2347427e-2d87-46e1-b80f-b43318ed6abb?auth=1

Comment: @VarmintLP Thanks. The rider is already on minimum (I found it now). I could only try the described repair update but that seems drastic given my PC worked this morning before the update..

Comment: @tomka In that case I would recommend to uninstall that update or if possible, to wait until their is an update to fix this. I didn't have that issue yet but it's good to have a heads up. ;)

Comment: 1. Have you tried changing the *scale and layout* settings? 2. Could *Ease of access* feature be turned on to *Make text bigger*? 3. You might check the dafault font, and change it: https://www.howtogeek.com/716407/how-to-change-the-default-system-font-on-windows-10/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you, I have by chance found a solution, see below. It is curious.

Comment: @VarmintLP Thank you again, I have by chance found a solution, see below. It is curious.

Answer (score 3):

By chance, I have found the solution. It is quite curious.

The option 'Make text bigger' under Settings --> Display was set to minimum size. See below. Note that I could only see this Display setting when I **connected my external monitor**. It was **not there** when working on the laptop without external monitor.

[image]

Next I set the setting to a **larger** value by sliding the rider to the right and clicked apply. Now everything was even larger. Then I reverted the setting to minimum size by sliding the rider all the way to the left and again clicking apply. When I did this, all text in all menus had reverted to its **real** minimum size (so, smaller than before and how it looked before the problem occurred).

Obviously this is a Windows bug but I do not know how to replicate it.